# Почему денвер ругается на скобку... хотя хостинг обрабатывает всё

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, стоял скрипт граббера на хостинге бесплатном, всё отлично работало , поставил его на денвер выходит вот такая ошибка...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in W:\home\3.ru\www\parser.php on line 13
```

13 строка в коде

```
$nick_names = ['Tomasch', 'FC SD', 'prickly', 'Казимира'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Новый синтаксис объявления массивов, доступен только начиная с версии PHP 5.4

```
$nick_names = ['Tomasch', 'FC SD', 'prickly', 'Казимира'];
```

В более старых версиях массивы объявляются только через конструкцию array()

```
$nick_names = array('Tomasch', 'FC SD', 'prickly', 'Казимира');
```

Если вам необходимо сохранить совместимость со старыми версиями, придется пользоваться конструкцией `array()`, даже если версия позволяет использовать новый сокращенный синтаксис `[]`.

Comment: Спасибо большое))) вроде денвер скачал недавно только ))

Comment: @Константин, а зачем вам Denwer, он же не поддерживается уже давно? Вы не хотите задействовать встроенный сервер PHP? Удобно, всегда под рукой, единственно, не очень удобно работать c роутингом в современных CMS.

Comment: Что это такое , можно поподробнее?)

Comment: @Константин, в общем не используйте Денвер — он умер. Если вам нужен именно комплект для веб-разработки, то можно, например, попробовать [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо просто не знал что он умер )) а вы бы не могли помочь, голову ломаю вот с этим вопросом [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507961/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-mysql-php)

Comment: @Константин А я бы openServer порекомендовал бы.http://open-server.ru/   тем более он даже php7 поддерживает сейчас

Comment: ой ребят, мы живем в мире облачных технологий, и никто из вас не сказал про c9.io :)