# Запись обработанных данных в Mysql (php)

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так)) вот есть код который не пойму как поправить правильно:

```
/* Таблица MySQL, в которой будут храниться данные */
$table = "test_table";

/* Создаем соединение */
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");

/* Выбираем базу данных. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее */
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

/* Составляем запрос для извлечения данных из полей "name", "email", "theme",
"message", "data" таблицы "test_table" */
$query = "SELECT id, nickname FROM $table";

/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    $data_fin = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data_fin;
}
$ups = "&noredir=9462fa1c293699b04eb15e8b8d84b9ba";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$nick_names = $row['nickname']; // пример произвольного массива ник-неймов
$length = count($nick_names);

$test1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM mytable");
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

    $url = "http://w2.dwar.ru/user_info.php?nick=" . urlencode($nick_names) . $ups;
    $page = getPage($url);
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
     $pos = strpos($content, '&lvl=');
     $content = substr($content, $pos);
     $pos = strpos($content, '&tSrc=images');
     $content = substr($content, 0, $pos);
     $content = str_replace('&lvl=','', $content);
 if (preg_match('/online=1/',$page)) {

$query = "INSERT INTO $table SET online='online', lvl='$content'";
    } else {

       $query = "INSERT INTO $table SET online='offline', lvl='$content'";
    }


}

}





/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

/* Закрываем соединение */
mysql_close();
```

Если вместо INSERT вписать Update то вообще ничего не будет происходить )) (в данный момент скрипт не работает, он создает дополнительное поле, с пустыми данными и записывает онлайн либо оффлайн в него... иногда еще уровень)

Когда же скрипт работает на вывод данных на текущую страницу вот таким вот образом:

```
if (preg_match('/online=1/',$page)) {

         echo '<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="prv[' . $nick_names . ']"><img src="http://www.dwar.ru/images/news-arrow.gif"></button> ' . $nick_names . ' [' . $content . ']<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/player_info.gif" border=0 width=10 height=10 align="absmiddle"></a> : <span style="color: green;"><b>Online</b></span><br><br>';
    } else {
        echo '<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="prv[' . $nick_names . ']"><img src="http://www.dwar.ru/images/news-arrow.gif"></button> ' . $nick_names . ' [' . $content . ']<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/player_info.gif" border=0 width=10 height=10 align="absmiddle"></a> : <span style="color: red;"><b>Offline</b></span><br><br>';
    }
```

Тоесть я вижу полноценный список всех людей с базы данных, но какой уровень и онлайн или нет после обработки выдается просто на страницу, не записывая в базу данных.

Как сделать так что бы после граббинга всё дописывалось в базу данных? к примеру по никнейму либо же по id ...

База данных содержит 4 поля:

```
-id
-nickname
-online
-lvl
```

Помогите пожалуйста, в данный момент обработанные данные выводятся сразу на страницу , без записи в базу, дело в том что нужно именно запись в базу без вывода на страницу, что б оно не единоразово записалось , а обновлялось , при каждом запросе этого кода.

Изначально таблица имея всего лишь `id` и `nickname` , весь список должен обработаться через этот код и дописать (обновить) все значения `online` и `lvl`.

Что я делаю не так ? )))

```
 if (preg_match('/online=1/',$page)) {

    $query = "UPDATE $table
              SET
                nickname = '$nick_names',
                online = 'online',
                lvl = '$content'
              WHERE id = {$row['id']}";

    } else {
    $query = "UPDATE $table
              SET
                nickname = '$nick_names',
                online = 'offline',
                lvl = '$content'
              WHERE id = {$row['id']}";
    }
```

Comment: Ну, начать можно с того, что он вносит именно то что Вы просите его внести, а именно статус и "иногда уровень" `online='online', lvl='$content'`, нужно как минимум добавить параметры `id` и `nickname` (если конечно у вас поле `id` это не уникальный идентификатор с автоинкрементом) + если вы хотите делать Update записи то нужно условие `WHERE` по которому мы будете определять какую конкретную запись обновить

Comment: id у всех уникальный, а что значит `иногда уровень` ?  я как понял через запятую идет перечисление полей...) сейчас попробую)

Comment: `if (preg_match('/online=1/',$page)) {

    $query = "UPDATE $table SET lvl='11' WHERE id = '11'";

      echo ''. $nick_names . '-онлайн, id-'. $id . ' , уровень - '.$content.'<br />';` вот код , выводится весь список все хорошо , но уровень не меняется на 11 у 11 айди ( в чем беда ?

Comment: Спасибо работает .. разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Получать уровень пробуйте так:

```
if(preg_match("~&lvl=(.*)&tSrc~",$html_page,$preg))
    print_r($preg);
$preg[1] - тут ваш уровень
```

Comment: уровень я и так получаю `$content` выводит уровень )) как это все в базу данных запихнуть не могу мучитюсь

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как запрос построить для ввода данных в таблицу , вот у меня 20 человек , в таблице есть всего лишь столбец с заполнеными id и никнеймами ) как это всё записать в таблицу(

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста ответ свой, что это и с чем это едят , я сделал уже что хотел

Comment: Пожалуйста обьясните как оно работает , на уровень , что б меньше кода было

Comment: Не работает такой парсер такой(( пожалуйста, пятый раз прошу помочь)